# Kivi: How to set Path for storing Output.txt file of Android app

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am making android app with kivy and python, I have function what will create record in TXT format, in my Project it is in same folder as the .PY file, but i know once i create .apk then it can be problem where the file will be stored.
For example I would like to store that Tracking.txt file in Download folder of Android device. How i can define this please?

This is how it is defined now, it should safe/open file where is the app.

```
import kivy
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform
import os

if platform == 'android':
    import android
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
    dir = primary_external_storage_path()
    download_dir_path = os.path.join(dir, 'Download')

Window.size = (480, 800)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1  # Set columns for main layout
        self.inside = GridLayout(cols=2, row_force_default=True,
                                 row_default_height=50, padding=20,
                                 spacing=10)  # Create a new grid layout
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Tracking Number \n Checker", halign="center", font_size=40))  # Top Label
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Work Number:", halign="center", font_size=20))  # Add a label widget
        self.worknumb = TextInput(text_validate_unfocus=True, multiline=False, font_size=20, halign="center")
        self.inside.add_widget(self.worknumb)
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Tracking \nNO. Scan:", halign="center", font_size=20))
        self.tracknumb = TextInput(multiline=False, font_size=15, halign="center")  # Create a Text input box stored in the name variable
        self.inside.add_widget(self.tracknumb)  # Add the text input widget to the GUI

        self.add_widget(self.inside)  # Add the interior layout to the main
        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40, size_hint =(.5, .5))  # Submit button
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.send_tracknumb)
        self.resultbox = Image(source="status.png")  #image box on bottom
        self.add_widget(self.resultbox)

        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.pressed)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_worknumb, 1)
    def pressed(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40 or keycode == 13 or keycode == 8:
            self.send_tracknumb(None)

    def focus_worknumb(self, _):
        self.worknumb.focus = True
    def focus_tracknumb(self, _):
        self.tracknumb.focus = True
    def send_tracknumb(self, _):
        tracknumb = self.tracknumb.text
        worknumb = self.worknumb.text
        errorsound = SoundLoader.load("incorrect.mp3")  # add sound to the scanning
        correctsound = SoundLoader.load("correct.ogg")
        self.tracknumb.text = ""  # Reset text to blank in each text input
        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_tracknumb, 0.2)
        f = open(os.path.join(download_dir_path, 'tracking.txt'), "a")
        tr = tracknumb
        wr = worknumb
        time = str(datetime.now())
```

Edit: I used the function suggested in post below, but now it showing that it cannot find the Android, what i somehow installed from the suggestion what pop up in Pycharm, but the storage and premmisions are not found.
What am i missing in Import part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code snippet to get hold of the `Download` directory path in android. And then use the path as appropriate.

```
from kivy.utils import platform
import os

if platform == 'android':
    from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
    dir = primary_external_storage_path()
    download_dir_path = os.path.join(dir, 'Download')
```

Comment: You can store the full path of your tracking.txt file like: os.path.join(download_dir_path, 'tracking.txt'). And then use that variable wherever you need the path for tracking.txt file. Also please note, for windows platform you need to define that path variable appropriately by an 'else' statement in the above 'if' statement. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes Thank you very much for your time, I will try it now, once i finish installing buildozer

Comment: Let's say you define the variable for full path for the file 'file_path'. Then file_path = os.path.join(download_dir_path, 'tracking.txt'). And then you use the 'file_path' variable in the 'open' function.

Comment: sory to be pain in a.. but i just noticed, as i have to run VM on slow pc with Linux to compile it, that the  from `android.storage` import could not be found, what should i add to the import list to find it please if I may?

Comment: You need to include ```android``` in the ```requirements``` section of ```buildozer.spec``` file.

Comment: I will try tomorrow probably, Thank you. I maybe replace all the txt file part if i manage to get the comunication to SQL working, I can connect to database but it is not inserting data